# ASP.NET WebAPI Template Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm not sure if this is a question that should be asked on SO, but I can't think of a better place to ask it.  What I want to know is: Does anyone out there actually use the Web API 4.5.2 Template that ships with Visual Studio.  I've been writing C# Web Applications for some time now, and I feel like these templates are bloated nightmares to work with.  They also seem to push developers away from understanding how things are actually working under the hood.  Do you agree or disagree, and should I be using these templates if I want to call myself a .Net Web Developer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ofcourse highly opinionated, but yes I agree; the default (MVC related) templates are bloated with unnecessary features and there's nothing lean and mean about them. I've used a custom template for a long time just to get around this (frustrating) problem.

Note that Visual Studio now has the option to create an *empty website* and gives you the option to only include *WebAPI*, not forcing you to include *ASP.NET MVC*. This produces a nice tiny project.

If you do experiment alot with *WebAPI* and you don't want your harddisks to be a cluster bomb full of Visual Studio projects, I can highly recommend *LinqPad*. With a tiny bit of code you can create a *self hosting* process and use it as a template. For example:

```
#define NONEST

void Main()
{
    string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

    try
    {
        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
        {
            // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result;

            Console.WriteLine("response: " + response);
            Console.WriteLine("result: " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // LinqPad keeps the AppDomain running to reduce compile time. 
        // Force app domain unload (Displays "Query ended unexpectedly")
        // You can also press shift-F5 to unload the AppDomain.

        AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Startup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values 
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```